# How to set dynamically outputs variables in a composite action

Tags: bash, github-actions

### Issue

I'm trying to set outputs variables **dynamically** in a **composite action** `action.yml` file with `bash`.

*Observation: I don't know what will be the outputs names, they are defined during the action execution using a loop.*

In the loop, I'm using the [new syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs#example-defining-outputs-for-a-job) to set the outputs:

```
echo "key=value" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

However, **the outputs variables can't be access** in the action following steps in a workflow.

### How to reproduce the issue

Relevant part of the implementation I'm using in the `action.yml` file:

```
runs:

  using: composite

  steps:

    - run: |

          [...] # Some code to extract and set the KEYS list
 
          for (( i=0; i<${#KEYS[@]}; i++ ))

          do

            RESULT= # Some code to extract KEY value according to KEY name

            echo "'${KEYS[$i]}' value is: $RESULT"
            
            NAME=$(echo "${KEYS[$i]}" | sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/-/g') # Convert KEY name to correct format without special character

            echo "'${KEYS[$i]}' output name will be: $NAME"

            echo "$NAME=$RESULT" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT # The problem seems to be here

          done

      shell: bash
```

Workflow I'm using to test the action:

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Call action
        id: read-file
        uses: <owner>/<action-repo>@main # Should set the outputs my-key and my-other-key
      
      - name: Print outputs
        run: |
           echo ${{ steps.read-file.outputs.my-key }}
           echo ${{ steps.read-file.outputs.my-other-key }}
```

### What I tried

- Checked [the output section for composite actions in the Official Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-composite-actions).
- Print each `key=value` before trying to use them to set the output (they are correctly generated)
- Set the **outputs** field in the `action.yml` file (but it only works if you know the output name value).

*Observation: As explained above, all the `echo` commands print the `$NAME` and `$RESULT` values as expected in the action. However, the `echo "$NAME=$RESULT" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` doesn't seem to work as expected, as I'm not able to access the output in the fallowing steps calling the actions.*

### Question

How can I set those multiple outputs variables dynamically in my **composite action** using `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests, it seems not to be possible to set outputs dynamically in a composite action yet using the `echo "key=value" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` syntax, without configuring the **output field name** in the action.

*Note: This behavior is supported for [Docker and Javascript actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-docker-container-and-javascript-actions), just not for [composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-composite-actions).*

---

At the moment, a workaround for **composite actions** could eventually be:

- Set all the `key=value` in a specific JSON in the action.
- Save the JSON as a specific output "result".
- Then, access the values by parsing the "result" JSON in further steps in the workflow.

It's not as flexible as for a Docker or a Javascript action, but it allows to have the same behavior for all os runners as well.

*PS: I'm open to other workarounds!*

Comment: Serializing to JSON is the workaround I thought of when reading the question, too. Another option could be exporting an associative array into the environment, though I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: I suspect the behavior for environment variables be the same as for outputs in composite actions. But it's worth a try! Thank you for sharing :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think arrays of any kind can be exported... still JSON, I guess.